# Oracle SQL Developer unable to export CLOB data

Tags: database, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

I have a CLOB field in the query result of the query that I am running on SQL Developer. Now, the problem is that on the older version of SQL Developer, when I export the query result as insert statement, it provides me the CLOB data as expected however on the latest version it doesn't export CLOB fields, just to be sure of the behavior, I tried the same with other tables having CLOB fields and it is the same.

[image]

**Export Output**

[image]

**SQL Versions**

With which it worked: Version 4.0.3.16
Where it is not working: Version 4.2.0.17.089

Based on my understanding it is the settings that is causing the problem which I cannot seem to find anywhere. I have checked everything inside the `Tools > Preferences` but there is no difference between the two versions and there is no specific setting for CLOB fields either.

Comment: [Possibly related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42244941/266304). Are you sure it worked *as insert statements* in 4.0.3? If it did were all the strings less than 4K; or are you sure it was a CLOB in both cases? I've just tested in 4.0.3 and the output was the same as you've shown (presumably from 4.2.0).

Comment: OK, depends where you export from; the docs say CLOBS aren't supported, and but I do see the CLOB column if I right-click in the Query Result window and export form there, which is what your Wizard screen suggests you are doing, in both 4.0.3 and 4.2.0. But not if I right-click on the table in the navigator, or pick Database Export from the tools menu. The two versions seem to be behaving consistently for me.

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanks for all your efforts, I have rechecked and hence I can confirm that both the tables I'm using have CLOB fields. It can't be a matter of 4K considering the fact that it is working for one of the version. You're right in saying that I am using Query Result to export however I didn't get whether that worked for you or not.

Comment: Yes, exporting from the Query Result window included the CLOB columns in both versions of SQL Developer. The other two ways of exporting excluded the CLOB column in both versions. I'm not aware of a setting that affects that either.

Comment: Painful experience here... the export tool did not include the `clob` columns and there are no warning mesages whatsoever - some columns were missing without notice. Using Query result window gives the correct results but you have to do each table one by one