# How to generate inserts when columns type is clob

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g, plsqldeveloper

I have a problem in Oracle, I need to generate inserts but the table have columns CLOB but I don't get information when generate the insert.

Someone know how to generate inserts with complete information using PL / SQL Developer preferably.

Thanks in advance.

I generate this

```
insert into spr_dat.spr_requerimientos (PLANTILLA_ENTRADA, PLANTILLA_RESPUESTA)
values ('<CLOB>', '<CLOB>');
```

I drop some pictures about problem.

1. Columns type CLOB
   https://github.com/jquishpe/image_oracle/blob/master/error01.png
2. Export results in SQL file
   https://github.com/jquishpe/image_oracle/blob/master/error02.png
3. Inserts
   https://github.com/jquishpe/image_oracle/blob/master/error03.png
4. Extract information
   https://github.com/jquishpe/image_oracle/blob/master/error04.png
5. Error when export table
   https://github.com/jquishpe/image_oracle/blob/master/error05.png

> Database: Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bi
>
> PL/SQL Developer: Version 12.0.7.1837 (64 bit) 01.226959

Comment: you may get better response contacting PL/SQL developer support.

Comment: You can find the answer here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42244941/how-to-export-clob-field-datas-in-oracle-sql-developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42244941/how-to-export-clob-field-datas-in-oracle-sql-developer)

Comment: How big are these clobs? Bigger than 4K characters?

Comment: That fifth error message is telling you you can't export CLOBs using a SQL export, you need to use the third tab, PLSQL Developer Export. This exports to a .PDE file which is a proprietary PLSQL Developer binary format and can only be imported through PLSQL Developer. If that doesn't suit, you will need to roll your own solution. Or have a look at [@FerencToth's `EXP_IMP_LOB` package in this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43539473/146325). (No warranty implied or intended).